# Prior Month for Prior Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been able to Declare and Set grabbing the prior months data.

```
DECLARE @FirstDayofPrevMonth datetime
SET @FirstDayofPrevMonth = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
DECLARE @LastDayofPrevMonth datetime  
SET @LastDayofPrevMonth = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

What I now need is to be able to set and declare prior month, prior year....

to be clear, this does work for me. I get the expected result which is Aug 2014.  What I'm looking to do, is get Aug 2013 and so on.

UPDATE:
I thought I would share two other pieces I added to my code that may be helpful to others.

I used the below answer and added to it

```
DECLARE @FirstDayofPrevMonth datetime
SET @FirstDayofPrevMonth = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
DECLARE @LastDayofPrevMonth datetime
SET @LastDayofPrevMonth = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

-- to be used for the prior year completed month

```
DECLARE @FirstDayofPrevMonthLY datetime
SET @FirstDayofPrevMonthLY = DATEADD(year,-1,@FirstDayofPrevMonth)
DECLARE @LastDayofPrevMonthLY datetime
SET @LastDayofPrevMonthLY = DATEADD(year,-1,@LastDayofPrevMonth)
```

--This is to be used if you want for dates in the current Quarter

```
DECLARE @FirstDayofCQ datetime
SET @FirstDayofCQ = DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
DECLARE @LastDayofCQ datetime
SET @LastDayofCQ =DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
```

--This is to be used for the Prior Quarter

```
DECLARE @FirstDayofPrevQ datetime
SET @FirstDayofPrevQ = DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
DECLARE @LastDayofPrevQ datetime
SET @LastDayofPrevQ = DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Comment: Looks like you already have a way to get the prior month, no? Is that not producing the result you want?

Comment: this gets me last month. I want last month for 2013. So August 2013.  I currently am getting Aug 2014 with this

Comment: `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-13,0)`

Comment: You're saying that if you have `13 March 2014` you want to return `13 February 2013`? What about if you have `13 January 2014`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @FirstDayofPrevMonthPriorYear datetime  
DECLARE @LastDayofPrevMonthPriorYear datetime  
SET @FirstDayofPrevMonthPriorYear = DATEADD(year,-1,@FirstDayofPrevMonth)
SET @LastDayofPrevMonthPriorYear = DATEADD(year,-1,@LastDayofPrevMonth)
```

Comment: um, yes...wow.  Wouldn't never have thought of that.  So simple!

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @FirstDayofPrevMonthPrevYear datetime

SET @FirstDayofPrevMonthPrevYear = (DATEADD(yy, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-1,0)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  it looks like this will work too